quarkus @QuarkusTest : ContextNotActiveException always raised on the 2nd test
env : Quarkus 2.16.12 / Java 17
I am a newbie on Quarkus and I am trying to add the first unit tests to quarkus app.
The bean i want to test is :
@RequestScoped
@Path("/config")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ConfigRS {
    ...
        @GET
    @Path("load")
    public ConfigResponse apiLoad() {
        final ConfigResponse response = new ConfigResponse();
        ...
        }
    
}

The 2  unit tests I wrote are the followings :
package com.deltaone;


import com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigException;
import com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigFile;
import com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigRS;
import io.quarkus.arc.Arc;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.InjectSpy;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;

import javax.enterprise.context.control.ActivateRequestContext;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


@QuarkusTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class ConfigRSTest {

    @InjectSpy
    ConfigRS crs;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        Arc.container().requestContext().activate();
    }

    @Test
    @ActivateRequestContext
    @Order(1)
    public void SuccessLoadFromHdfs() throws Exception {

        doNothing().when(crs).loadFileFromHdfs();

        List<ConfigFile> mockFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        mockFiles.add(new ConfigFile());

        doReturn(mockFiles).when(crs).readConfigInfo();

        given()
                .when().get("/portal/config/load")
                .then()
                .body("status", org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo("ok"))
                .statusCode(200);
    }

    @Test
    @ActivateRequestContext
    @Order(2)
    public void FailedLoadFromHdfs() throws Exception {
        doThrow(new ConfigException("Load failed")).when(crs).loadFileFromHdfs();

        given()
                .when().get("/portal/config/load")
                .then()
                .body("status", org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo("error"))
                .statusCode(200);
    }

}

when I execute the tests, I get the following error :
C:\Users\nbelot.IV\.jdks\temurin-17.0.10\bin\java.exe -ea -Djacoco-agent.destfile=C:\workspaces\github\aa-portal\portal\target/jacoco-ut.exec -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager "-Dmaven.home=C:\Users\nbelot.IV\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.security.jca=ALL-UNNAMED -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Users\nbelot.IV\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate\lib\idea_rt.jar=63154:C:\Users\nbelot.IV\AppData\Local\Programs\IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\nbelot.IV\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_arg_file688366094 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit5 com.deltaone.ConfigRSTest
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/nbelot.IV/.m2/repository/org/jboss/slf4j/slf4j-jboss-logmanager/1.2.0.Final/slf4j-jboss-logmanager-1.2.0.Final.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/nbelot.IV/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.10/logback-classic-1.2.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLoggerFactory]
2024-04-02 09:08:19,704 INFO  [io.qua.arc.pro.BeanProcessor] (build-1) Found unrecommended usage of private members (use package-private instead) in application beans:
    - @PostConstruct callback com.deltaone.blackbox.web.system.GaranteLogger#init(),
    - @Inject field com.deltaone.blackbox.web.admin.repository.ConfigInfoRepository#dataSource,
    - Bean constructor void <init>(io.agroal.api.AgroalDataSource defaultDataSource) on com.deltaone.holistix.dataaccess.PortalDBConnectionFactory
    - and 9 more - please enable debug logging to see the full list
2024-04-02 09:08:20,856 WARN  [io.qua.config] (main) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.log.console.json.fields.host-name.field-name" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo
2024-04-02 09:08:22,289 INFO  [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (main) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.deltaone.blackbox.web.IdmcApplication from Application class com.deltaone.blackbox.web.PortalApplication
2024-04-02 09:08:22,290 INFO  [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (main) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.deltaone.blackbox.web.mdm.MdmRS from Application class com.deltaone.blackbox.web.PortalApplication
2024-04-02 09:08:22,291 INFO  [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (main) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.deltaone.blackbox.web.admin.AdminRS from Application class com.deltaone.blackbox.web.PortalApplication
2024-04-02 09:08:22,291 INFO  [org.jbo.res.res.i18n] (main) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigRS from Application class com.deltaone.blackbox.web.PortalApplication
2024-04-02 09:08:23,275 INFO  [io.agr.pool] (main) Datasource '<default>': Initial size smaller than min. Connections will be created when necessary
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:23.601+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"Resource not found: /id","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:23.609+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"Resource not found: /id.pub","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.223+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"IDMC System started","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.303+02:00","level":"WARN","message":"Datasource '<default>': Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.","thread":"agroal-11","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.304+02:00","level":"ERROR","message":"Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.","thread":"executor-thread-0","stacktrace":"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:253)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)\r\n\tat io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:226)\r\n\tat io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:536)\r\n\tat io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:517)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\r\n\tat io.agroal.pool.util.PriorityScheduledExecutor.beforeExecute(PriorityScheduledExecutor.java:75)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\r\nCaused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:547)\r\n\tat java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:602)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)\r\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)\r\n\t... 12 more\r\n","errorType":"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException","errorMessage":"Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.309+02:00","level":"ERROR","message":"Failed to clean up sync table: ","thread":"executor-thread-0","stacktrace":"java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke \"java.sql.Connection.createStatement()\" because \"conn\" is null\r\n\tat com.deltaone.blackbox.web.system.Synchronizer.doCleanup(Synchronizer.java:205)\r\n\tat com.deltaone.blackbox.web.system.Synchronizer_ClientProxy.doCleanup(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.deltaone.blackbox.web.system.Synchronizer_ScheduledInvoker_doCleanup_a49a15323a4ac550dcb1c682c262bc970cbd0c50.invokeBean(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.DefaultInvoker.invoke(DefaultInvoker.java:24)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.scheduler.common.runtime.StatusEmitterInvoker.invoke(StatusEmitterInvoker.java:35)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.SimpleScheduler$ScheduledTask.doInvoke(SimpleScheduler.java:333)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.SimpleScheduler$ScheduledTask$1.handle(SimpleScheduler.java:314)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.scheduler.runtime.SimpleScheduler$ScheduledTask$1.handle(SimpleScheduler.java:310)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$null$0(ContextBase.java:137)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:264)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextBase.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextBase.java:135)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:581)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)\r\n\tat org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)\r\n","errorType":"java.lang.NullPointerException","errorMessage":"Cannot invoke \"java.sql.Connection.createStatement()\" because \"conn\" is null","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.424+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"portal 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 2.16.12.Final) started in 12.659s. Listening on: http://localhost:8081","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.425+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"Profile test activated. ","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:26.425+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"Installed features: [agroal, cdi, flyway, jdbc-postgresql, logging-json, micrometer, narayana-jta, reactive-routes, rest-client, rest-client-jackson, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, resteasy-multipart, scheduler, security, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-jwt, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx]","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:30.733+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"Starting to load configuration from HDFS","thread":"executor-thread-0","deltaoneLogCategory":"audit","requestId":"","token":"","client":"","event":"Load config","object":null,"result":"SUCCESS","details":{"body":"{\"status\":\"ok\",\"message\":null,\"signature\":\"invalid\",\"file\":[{\"name\":null,\"timestamp\":0,\"content\":null,\"readOnly\":false,\"size\":0}]}"},"context":"Mediation Configuration"}

org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.TestInstantiationException: Failed to create test instance

    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.initTestState(QuarkusTestExtension.java:770)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:737)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: RequestScoped context was not active when trying to obtain a bean instance for a client proxy of CLASS bean [class=com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigRS, id=688d9526726460b2949d045bc5749a6c249737c7]
    - you can activate the request context for a specific method using the @ActivateRequestContext interceptor binding
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:55)
    at com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigRS_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
    at com.deltaone.blackbox.web.config.ConfigRS_ClientProxy.arc_contextualInstance(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.ClientProxy.unwrap(ClientProxy.java:52)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.ClientProxyUnwrapper.apply(ClientProxyUnwrapper.java:15)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.internal.CreateMockitoSpiesCallback.createSpyAndSetTestField(CreateMockitoSpiesCallback.java:31)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.mockito.internal.CreateMockitoSpiesCallback.afterConstruct(CreateMockitoSpiesCallback.java:22)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.AbstractTestWithCallbacksExtension.invokeCallbacks(AbstractTestWithCallbacksExtension.java:158)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.AbstractTestWithCallbacksExtension.invokeAfterConstructCallbacks(AbstractTestWithCallbacksExtension.java:64)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.initTestState(QuarkusTestExtension.java:767)
    ... 66 more

{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:32.042+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"IDMC System stopped","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}
{"timestamp":"2024-04-02T09:08:32.072+02:00","level":"INFO","message":"portal stopped in 0.088s","thread":"main","context":"Mediation Configuration"}

Process finished with exit code -1

enter image description here
The second test always fails with :
Caused by: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: RequestScoped context was not active when trying to obtain a bean instance for a client proxy of CLASS bean [class=com.empirix.redbox.web.config.ConfigRS, id=688d9526726460b2949d045bc5749a6c249737c7]
    - you can activate the request context for a specific method using the @ActivateRequestContext interceptor binding

When I change the order of the tests, the second test still fails.
Executing each test individually with the IDE completes successfully.
=> something about the context broke after the first test, but dont known what.
As long as I am newbie to quarkus, help will be appreciated ;-)
Regards.
N.

Mocking JAX-RS  Resources is definitely not going to work well :)

Is it supposed to work ???

It's totally untested and if I am not one bit surprised it does not work.

I migrated Quarkus from 2.16.12 to 3.9.1 and no more errors : the unit tests now  complete successfully.
